# How to display raw XML string in browser

Tags: asp.net, html, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an XML string that I actually want to display on screen.

I have tried using Html.Raw(myXMLString) but it displays without the node names, I have tried outputting without Html.Raw but same result

How can I display a raw XML string in the browser?

Comment: Do you want to display it as content or just a part of your html page?

Comment: <pre>xml goes here</pre>, or <code> or <textarea> etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Html.Encode before sending it back

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@myXMLString
```

That should do the trick?

Otherwise, set the HTTP content-type header to `text/plain` and send raw. I imagine your header currently is `text/html` hence you need to escape it.

Comment: myXmlString is being populated via AJAX/JSON

Comment: What is the AJAX/JSON request in Fiddler? And what is the value of the string in the debugger watch?

Comment: I can't show you the XML as its sensitive but I know its correct and that XML is being sent to the browser because when I view the source its all there

Comment: Something is WRONG with the header you are sending back.... look at your content-type response header... what is it?

Comment: The page is text/html and the AJAX response is application/json;

Comment: If AJAX **response** is application/json then here is your problem. It will treat it as JSON.

Comment: I have just gone through the data that is built up and returned as JSON and done HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() and now it appears ok in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `<code></code>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Is XML the only thing you're trying to display? What about changing the content type?:

```
Page.Request.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

If you're only trying to display a section of XML on the page, I would try rendering it into a `<pre>` tag.

I'm not sure about this one, but you might be able to use a `Literal` too, with the Mode set to `PassThrough`.

Comment: Problem is I don't know when I have XML as all I have is a DataTable with rows & columns

Comment: See second suggestion, rendering it to a `<pre>` element

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The issue I have is that I am just looping over all rows and columns outputting the data so I dont want the pre tag for everything

Comment: Add some logic to determine if the cell content is XML, and take it from there.